# Persisting spacial (Point) properties from Neo4j using java ogm

Tags: java, neo4j, spatial, neo4j-ogm

I have a neo4j database, and one of the nodes in the database has the following:

`<id>:91671 coordinates: point({srid:7203, x:-4.327197062, y:52.03857589}) description: "home"`

I am trying to make a model of this in java - so:

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Property;
import org.neo4j.ogm.types.spatial.CartesianPoint2d;

@NodeEntity (label="Location")
public class Location
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }  

    @Property(name="description")
    String description;

    @Property(name="coordinates")
    CartesianPoint2d coordinates; // problem is here      
}
```

When I try to use ogm to map the node into the object, I get the following error:

> org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.InvalidPropertyFieldException: 'Location#coordinates' is not persistable as property but has not been marked as transient.

I have tried various other types for `coordinates`, and have also tried to use a converter (based on [the ogm documentation - see 3.10.2](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:type-conversion)); but each time I get an error.

What is the correct way to do this mapping between a neo4j Point of srid 7203, and a type in java? Why does it say that it's not persistable, and what's my alternatives?

*note: I am aware that my Points should probably be srid 4326 as I'm talking about latitudes and longitudes - I'm not sure why they're not - but let's solve the problem as-is for now*

Comment: did you try PointValue ?

Comment: @TheCrusher that gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you enabled the native types in ogm properties as

```
use-native-types=true
```

or in configuration builder

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
        .uri("bolt://neo4j:password@localhost")
        .useNativeTypes()   //this enables using the spatial and temporal data 
        .build()            //  types in ogm
```

and in your pojo use CartesianPoint2d/CartesianPoint3d or GeographicPoint2d/GeographicPoint3d depending on the data type you have in graph.

```
@Property(name="coordinates")
CartesianPoint2d coordinates;
```